# Using "however" in mid position

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1- Are there any ways ***however*** in which new technology can help
>   support our traditions and help keep them alive ? ([Source](https://www.examenglish.com/IELTS/IELTS_academic_writing_part2_2.htm))
>
> 2- This does not mean ***however*** that all tasks in the child
>   rearing process should be shared equally. ([Source](https://www.examenglish.com/IELTS/IELTS_academic_writing_part2_1.htm))

---

Can I change the position of "however" in the sentences above?

> 1b- Are there, ***however***, any ways in which new technology can
>   help support our traditions and help keep them alive ?
>
> 2b- This does not, ***however***, mean that all tasks in the child
>   rearing process should be shared equally.

Comment: Or, at the start of the sentence: "However, . . ."

Comment: Increasingly, the modern style is *not* to set off such "relocatable adverbial elements" with commas (including the first comma in this sentence itself, which is just me showing my age). If you wouldn't pause in speech, there's no good reason to write the commas.